# Signing an Android app with a single .jks file between multiple developers

Tags: android, build.gradle, jks, android-app-signing

Hello android community,

We have an android team with 6 developers. When we create an .aab release file, we must share the .jks file among ourselves. And in the build.gradle file, we always need to change the path to the .jks file (due to different operating systems, different folder that has the .jks file). My question is is there any way to write some gradle script to only use one path for a .jks file? Or do you know other ways to do it?

Of course, we can put our .jks file in our project folder and not worry about the path. But we don't want to put .jks in the project folder for security reasons.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use the environment variable, set the sign key file path to the environment, and in the Gradle script read this environment.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv('JKS_FILE_PATH'))
        }
    }
}
```